# "An erratum to" vs "Erratum to" vs "Erratum"

Tags: latin

I have had to write an erratum (single) to one of my papers recently. I searched the internet and I found out that there are at least three versions as follows:

1. An erratum to "the title of the paper".
2. Erratum to "the title of the paper".
3. Erratum: "the title of the paper".

I chose the pattern number 1, but I was wondering which one of these patterns are more grammatically correct?

When there are more than one error to address in the paper, I suppose there is only one option (Errata to "the title of the paper"). Am I right?

Comment: If you want to [stick with majority usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+is+more+than+one%2Cthere+are+more+than+one&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=), you'll be "more right" if you say *"When there **is** more than one error..."*

Comment: How did 'to "the title of the paper"' come into that, please? I happen to think you're asking about errors "in", not "to" anything but still unless it's spelling or typography, I suggest neither it nor they is or are 'to "the title of the paper"' or anything similar…

Comment: Wikipedia has a very interesting discussion of ["erratum" versus "corrigendum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erratum) on its page for Erratum. It's worth considering if you ever reach find yourself wishing to distinguish between production errors and author errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are probably right, at least according to "The Cambridge Guide to English Usage" where, after a long explanation on words of two or more syllables that end in *-um*, Pam Peters says:

> A few scholarly words ending in *-um* are found with Latin plurals everywhere in the world, namely *addenda*, ... , **errata**, ... , *ova*.

So, according to that book, you should use **errata** to pluralize **erratum**.

Comment: Data is the plural of datum and schemata is the plural or schema, but why did those ^%*($@?!! at google and microsoft insisted on using datas and schemas and now we have to use these annoying terms too.